# WebAudioAPI sometimes drops scheduled fade values

Tags: javascript, web-applications, web-audio-api

Ehy everyone,
I'm developing a musical web-application using the Web Audio API, and I'm facing a problem that I cannot understand.

The app basically works like this: the user navigates through a full-screen image, on which there are some specific points associated with specific sounds. The app plays the sounds that are closer to the user, and fade them out when the user gets away.

The problem occurs (not every time) when the user is in a position where there are more than two sounds (3 or 4, but sometimes also 2 is enough) playing, and then goes in a "silent" position.

In that case the fades are somehow dropped and the sounds are abruptly interrupted. I can see from the logs that it enters the fading function, but it doesn't execute the scheduled gain curves.

To be more clear, here's an example of the steps my algorithm does:

- when the user is in the position A, let's say 3 sounds are playing;
- the user moves to position B and an event is fired when the action is finished;
- the algorithm calculates how many sounds are associated to position B: zero;
- performs a comparison with sounds in position A and calculates that sound 1, 2 an 3 are gone and they need to be stopped with a fade out;
- for each sound invokes fadeOut function, which schedules fade values with WebAudioAPI methods, and schedules stop action with setTimeout();

The result is that the sound remains with maximum volume till the stop function is invoked.

Here's the fadeOut() function:

```
StreamSound.prototype.fadeOut = function (fadeTime) {
const self = this;
if (self.isPlaying()) {
    if (!fadeTime) {
        console.warn(`Missing argument fadeTime. Set to 1 second`);
        fadeTime = 1;
    }
    var currGain = self.masterGain.gain.value;
    var curTime = self.context.currentTime;
    self.masterGain.gain.cancelScheduledValues(curTime);
    self.masterGain.gain.setValueAtTime(currGain, curTime);
    self.masterGain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0.0001, curTime + fadeTime);
    self.fading = true;
    setTimeout(function () {
        // If has not secondary streams
        if (self.secondaryStream === undefined) {
            console.log(`No secondary streams -> stop`);
            self.pause();
        } else if (!self.secondaryStream.isPlaying()) {
            console.log(`Not playing secondary streams -> stop`);
            self.pause();
        } else {
            self.playing = false;
        }
        self.fading = false;
        console.log(`Fade out stream finished [ ID: ${self.index} ]`);
    }, fadeTime * 1000 + 25);
    console.log(`Fading out stream [ ID: ${self.index} ]`);
} else {
    console.warn(`Cannot fade out. Sound not playing [ ID: ${self.index} ]`);
}
};
```

I suppose that probably that's due to scheduling issues, or can it be something related with JS thread management?

I know is not easy to help me just with these informations, but maybe someone had a similar problem.

Thanks in any case,
Francesco

---

**EDIT: I opened another post with a more general description and also a link to the source code and an online beta version** -> 
[WebAudioAPI musical application: clicks and crackles and abrupt stops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361436/webaudioapi-musical-application-clicks-and-crackles-and-abrupt-stops)

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing it happen in-place.  My guess is that currGain isn't getting the proper value back (it's not really "the current value", it's "the last scheduled or set value").  I'd suggest adding logging  a bunch of debugging info, like the currGain values whenever your fadeOut is called, and when the pause() is called.  It shouldn't be a thread management issue.

Comment: Mhm I don't think it's a problem related to the currGain value. The `fadeOut()` method is called only once (so the `.setValueAtTime(currGain, curTime)`.
I tried logging the value and the result is the same (the correct current  gain) whether I have the abrupt stop or the correct fade out. Thank you anyways.

Comment: `cancelScheduledValues` also does funny things.  If you can, use `cancelAndHoldAtTime` which makes holds the value at the cancellation time.  Then you probably don't need `currGain` and `setValueAtTime`, because that's the value `cancelAndHoldAtTime` produces.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried but it didn't work. 
I tried a lot of solutions but none of them worked. I'm increasingly convinced it's a performance-related issue when multiple sounds are playing,

Comment: Do you thinks that's possible that if I'm calling the fadeOut function from a setTimeout it drops the scheduled values?